# How to separate Slack blocks into a separate file

Tags: javascript, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm working on a slack bot in JS, and using Slack's "block kit" to format the messages. However, quite often I get a function that looks like this:

```js
app.command('/workspace-request', async ({ command, ack, respond }) => {
  await ack();

  //posts message to user
  await app.client.chat.postEphemeral({
    channel: command.channel_id,
    user: command.user_id,
    text: "Your request has been sent"
  })

  const blocks = [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "New Workspace Request:"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": `*User:* @${command.user_name}`
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": `*Description:* ${command.text}`
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "actions",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "button",
          "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Add to tasks"
          },
          "style": "primary",
          "value": "RequestApprove"
        },
        {
          "type": "button",
          "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Deny"
          },
          "style": "danger",
          "value": "RequestDeny"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]


  //posts message to workspace core
  await app.client.chat.postMessage({
    channel: "workspace-core",
    link_names: true,
    blocks: blocks


  })

  console.log(command)
});
```

Most of the code is just formatting the block kit text, and it makes it difficult to navigate. Is there a common way to organize this code so the blocks aren't taking up so much space? I tried making it into a separate file, but I ran into issues when trying to reference it in the main file, and I wasn't convinced that's the best way to do it. Any suggested would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual method is that you can keep the block kit as separate json file.
And read block from that file.

Please find sample code below:

```
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      try {        
        const block   = JSON.parse(data); 

      **// use block accordingly**
        
      } catch (e) {
        
      }
    });
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there any way I could also add variable values to the string? For example the block with text `"*Description:* ${command.text}"`

Comment: Resolved. For others wondering, you can add data to the parsed file in the main function with `block[1].text.text = \`*User:* @${command.user_name}\``